# serialization ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization, non-printing-characters

I want to serialize the Arraylist of type `ArrayList<Class>`
and the class contains two Arraylist of primitive type

```
public class Keyword {

    private long id;
    private long wid;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Integer> rank;
    private int month;
    private float avg;
    private ArrayList<String> date;
        ... and so on
}
```

How can i do that?

Lots of thanks in advance

Comment: Searching through google will be much quicker

Comment: Also, serialize for what purpose? Can you choose the output type (i.e. can you use JSON)?

Comment: yeah i found tutorials on google but i got confuse with the another arrylist in Class

Comment: i want to serialize to persist the arrylist... such that i can have use it later in the application. May be i can use JSON if the purpose is solved

Comment: @fmucar this was the first result on google, time travel

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use Serializable, you should have no problems, because ArrayList is Serializable just as String and every primitive type. `public class Keyword implements Serializable {}` should do. You can read more about this method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). However there are a lot of other options for serialization. So please be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

Implement and Interface 
`public class Keyword implements Serializable {}` and Simply Use the method of **"Object output stream"**
and **"Object input stream"** to Serialize and De-serialize the object.

and Arrylist can be Serialize as normal any data type can serialized.

Answer (score 0):

inherit the serialization interface in the that class which calss object you want to serialize.

after that use the ObjectOutput for serialize the object and use the writeObject method for serialize the object.