# How to serialize ArrayList of objects?

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, subclass, extend

> I want to serialize an arraylist of **Item** but it doesn't work....
>
> my **Item** class extends **Stuff** class and has some *subclasses*.
>
> all of my classes implement Serilalizable.
>
> i have this part :
>
> ```
> try{
> // Serialize data object to a file
> ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("MyData.ser"));
> out.writeObject(myData);
> out.close();
>
> // Serialize data object to a byte array
> ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
> out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
> out.writeObject(myData);
> out.close();
>
> // Get the bytes of the serialized object
> byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
> } catch (IOException e) {
> }
> ```
>
> my classes :
>
> ```
> public class Stuff implements Serializeable{
> ....
> some protected fields
> .
> .
> }
>
> public class Item extends Stuff implements Serializable{
> ...
> ..
> .
> } and some subclasses of Item:
>
> public class FirstItem extends Item implements Serializable{
> ...
> }
>
> public class SecondItem extends Item implements Serializable{
> ...
> } ... I want to serialize an object contains ArrayList of <Item> that has objects of Item's subclasses (FirstItem,SecondItem,...)
> ```
>
> **i think informations are sufficient...**

**it's just a little mistake and now works correctly...
I'm sorry for my stupid question.**

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Could you please post the code you tried but didn't work, so we will be able to answer your question more specifically.

Comment: How do you serialize it (what libraries do you use)? And what your classes are looking like? What do you need to serialize in them? And what does "doesn't work" means?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785955/serialization-arraylist-java

Comment: Please #define "doesn't work". Does it throw an exception? Deserialize to nonsense? Set fire to your pants?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description. Try again.

Comment: Code added. i use java.io.Serializable class and without that ArrayList<Item> i can serialize my object.

Comment: please answer.... why you make it on hold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can serialize class of ArrayList like this

```
public class MyData implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String title;
    private ArrayList<String> tags;
    ...

    public String getTitle() {
    }
}
```

And to create serializable

```
    ArrayList<MyData> myData = new ArrayList<MyData>();

try{
    // Serialize data object to a file
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("MyData.ser"));
    out.writeObject(myData);
    out.close();

    // Serialize data object to a byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
    out.writeObject(myData);
    out.close();

    // Get the bytes of the serialized object
    byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Why don't you need to set the ID of each list?

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a leap here that you are trying to serialize to something like json?

if so, you can use jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try
{
    final String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString( _integrationSettings );
    // do something with the string...
}
catch( IOException e )
{
    // use a logger to output error
}
```

You can also deserialize with jackson as well...

A more detailed example here: http://blog.inflinx.com/2012/05/10/using-jackson-for-javajson-conversion/

Note: you can do similar for XML.