# Kafka Streams table transformations

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I've got a table in SQL Server that I'd like to stream to Kafka topic, the structure is as follows:

```
(UserID, ReportID)
```

This table is going to be continuously changed (records added, inserted, no updates)

I'd like to transform this into this kind of structure and put into Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "UserID": 1,
  "Reports": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}
```

Examples I've seen so far are logs or click-stream which and do not work in my case.

Is this kind of use case possible at all? I could always just look at `UserID` changes and query database, but that seems naive and not the best approach.

#### Update

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyDemo {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("Hello KTable!");

    final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();

    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    KStream<Long, Long> reportPermission = builder.stream(TOPIC);

    KTable<Long, ArrayList<Long>> result = reportPermission
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(
            new Initializer<ArrayList<Long>>() {
              @Override
              public ArrayList<Long> apply() {
                return null;
              }
            },
            new Aggregator<Long, Long, ArrayList<Long>>() {
              @Override
              public ArrayList<Long> apply(Long key, Long value, ArrayList<Long> aggregate) {
                aggregate.add(value);
                return aggregate;
              }
            },
            new Serde<ArrayList<Long>>() {
              @Override
              public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {}

              @Override
              public void close() {}

              @Override
              public Serializer<ArrayList<Long>> serializer() {
                return null;
              }

              @Override
              public Deserializer<ArrayList<Long>> deserializer() {
                return null;
              }
            });

    result.to("report-aggregated-topic");

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, createStreamProperties());
    streams.cleanUp();
    streams.start();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
  }

  private static final String TOPIC = "report-permission";

  private static final Properties createStreamProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "report-permission-app");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "broker:9092");

    return props;
  }
}
```

I'm actually getting stuck at aggregate stage because I cannot write a proper SerDe for `ArrayList<Long>` (not enough skills yet), lambdas seem not to work on aggregator - it doesn't know what's the type of `agg`:

```
KTable<Long, ArrayList<Long>> sample = builder.stream(TOPIC)
    .groupByKey()
    .aggregate(
        () -> new ArrayList<Long>(),
        (key, val, agg) -> agg.add(val),
        longSerde
    );
```

Comment: Aggregation with Lambdas should work. Check out this example: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/3.3.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/TopArticlesLambdaExample.java#L211-L229

Comment: For Serds: You can picky reuse existing `LongSerde` of course. The basic pattern would be to serialized the size of the array list first, followed by each individual long value. And in deserialization you do the same. First, de-serialize the size, and than know how many entries to expect and deserialize all of the individually. Or you write a list-serializer from scratch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793885/how-to-serialize-arraylist-of-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Kafka's Connect API to get the data from SQL Server into Kafka. I am not aware of any specific connector for SQL Server but you can use any generic JDBC based connector: https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

To process data you can use Kafka's Streams API. You can simply `aggregate()` all report per user. Something like this:

```java
KTable<UserId, List<Reports>> result =
    builder.stream("topic-name")
           .groupByKey()
           // init a new empty list and
           // `add` the items to the list in the actual aggregation
           .aggregate(...);

result.to("result-topic");
```

Check out the docs for more details about Streams API: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html

> Note, that you need to make sure that the list of reports does not grow unbounded. Kafka has some (configurable) maximum message size and the whole list will be contained in a single message. Thus, you should estimate the maximum message size and apply the corresponding configuration (-> `max.message.bytes`) before going into production. Check out configs at the webpage: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Finally, you use Connect API to push the data into Elastic Search. There are multiple different connector available (I would of course recommend the Confluent one). More details about Connect API: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html

Comment: I will definitely check this out. Will reply tomorrow how this turned out to work.

Comment: Could you help a little bit extra? I'm quite stuck just because I lack Java skills. Have updated my question.

Answer (score -4):

Directly this kind of approach is not allowed in SQL and Kafka Streams, However the use case is possible and can be implemented as follows:

1) Write a custom application over SQL server using SOLRJ APIs which will hit Solr instance whenever a DML (Insert, Update, Delete etc ) operation is performed in SQL.
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

2) Use Solr SQL Data Import Handler by using it SQL Server will automatically inform solr whenever a DML (Insert, Update, Delete etc ) operation will occur in SQL.
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler