# Cannot resolve Serde with An Array List KAFKA

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm getting a compilation error when trying to create a new topic with KafkaStream object.

My new topic should contain a key and a value which is an `Array`.
Here is my code :

```
  Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();   
 // Cannot create a Serde of  an ArrayList
  Serde<String> arrayListSerde = Serdes.String();     
  KStream<String, String> stats = builder.stream("parking-rows-stats"); 

  KStream<String, List<String>> parkingCountAndTypeStream = stats                                                
            .selectKey((key, jsonRecordString) -> extractParkingName(jsonRecordString))                            
            .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key, extractPlaceTypeAndNumber(value))); 
  //Compilation error in this line               
  parkingCountAndTypeStream.to("parking-typeandnbfreeplaces-updates", Produced.with(stringSerde,arrayListSerde));
```

Comment: Have you tried using the serdes from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365884/issue-with-arraylist-serde-in-kafka-streams-api

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Does it say you have a `Serde<String>`, not `Serde<List<String>>`. Also, why not convert your values into a `JsonArray` that you can use with StringSerializer?

Comment: I want to have a key with 2 corresponding value , can you put in responses another solution please?