# How to combine different messages to 1 output message with KStreams?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I am really new to kafka streams world and have just beginners level knowledge in this area.
In our current application we receive json messages from Kafka topic in below format:

**Message1**

```
{
  "projectId": "Project1",
  "userId": "User1",
  "actions": [
    {
      "APP_MESSAGE_ID": "27",
      "category": "FA"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Message2**

```
{
  "projectId": "Project1",
  "userId": "User1",
  "actions": [
    {
      "APP_MESSAGE_ID": "28",
      "category": "FA"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Message3**

```
{
  "projectId": "Project2",
  "userId": "User1",
  "actions": [
    {
      "APP_MESSAGE_ID": "29",
      "category": "PD"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now we want to push it to destination topic in this format:

**Desired destination Output message**

```
[
  {
    "projectId": "Project1",
    "data": [
      {
        "APP_MESSAGE_ID": "27",
        "category": "FA"
      },
      {
        "APP_MESSAGE_ID": "28",
        "category": "FA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "projectId": "Project2",
    "data": [
      {
        "APP_MESSAGE_ID": "29",
        "category": "PD"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have managed to write for my input topic as below

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Input-Message.*");
KStream<String, Object> sourceStream = builder.stream(pattern);
KTable aggregatedTable =
            sourceStream
                .filter((k, v) -> v != null)
                .mapValues(v -> getAMModelFromMessage(v))
                .groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v != null ? v.getProjectId() : null, v))
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
                .aggregate(ArrayList::new, (k, v, list) -> {
                        list.add(v);
                        return list;
                    }
                    , Materialized.as("NewStore").withValueSerde(new ArrayListSerde(Serdes.String()))
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()));

KStream<Object, ArrayList<AMKafkaMessage>> outputStream = aggregatedTable.toStream();

        

outputStream.to("destination_topic");
```

I have implemented(used) ArrayListSerde, ArrayListSerializer and ArrayListDeserializer classes as per this question:
[Issue with ArrayList Serde in Kafka Streams API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365884/issue-with-arraylist-serde-in-kafka-streams-api)

**AMKafkaMessage** is my model class as below

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class AMKafkaMessage {

    private String projectId;
    private String userId;
}
```

and written below method to get its instance via parsing it from json

```
private AMKafkaMessage getAMModelFromMessage(Object message) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            
            AMKafkaMessage amKafkaMessage = gson.fromJson(message,
                AMKafkaMessage.class);
            return amKafkaMessage;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred while decrypting message: {}", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And want to write to topic named "destination_topic"

```
"destination_topic"
```

Any help to achieve this would be really appreciated.
Also please let me know if I am doing (or thinking) it wrong way about how streams should be utilised.
Thanks in advance.

Above code is giving me exceptions like

```
   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException while producing data to topic kafka-stream-NewStore-repartition. A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue / value type: com.admin.model.kafkaModel.AMKafkaMessage). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters (for example if using the DSL, `#to(String topic, Produced<K, V> produced)` with `Produced.keySerde(WindowedSerdes.timeWindowedSerdeFrom(String.class))`).
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:152) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:129) ~[kafka-streams-2.6.2.jar:?]
```

Failing here [image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message means, that the specified Serdes do not match the actual data type. You did specify `StringSerde / StringSerde` for key and value (seems those come from `StreamsConfig`), but the actually data types are `KeyValue / AMKafkaMessage`.

Given your program this makes sense.

```
.mapValues(v -> getAMModelFromMessage(v))
```

This transform the value into `AMKafkaMessage`. When you do the `groupBy` you trigger a repartitioning, so you will need to set a corresponding serde for the value using `Grouped` parameter (otherwise, Kafka Streams falls back to the serdes from the config that seems to be set to `StringSerde`).

```
.groupBy(..., Grouped.valueSerde(/* set Serded for AMKafkaMessage type */)
```

Furthermore, you do

```
.groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v != null ? v.getProjectId() : null, v))
```

This returns a `KeyValue` pair for the key. Note, that `groupBy` does not change the input record value, but the specified `KeyValueMapper` is supposed to only return the new key. Ie, for input `<k1,v1>` the result key-value-pair for your code would be `<<p1,v>, v>` (assuming `p1` is extracted from the value).

I assume, you actually want to do:

```
.groupBy((k, v) -> v != null ? v.getProjectId() : null)
```

to set the projectId as new key, and get `<p1,v>` as result?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I managed to get it working with casting list of object to String and ended up using String serde for communication.